# Posicionar o campo CEP no checkout Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugin-wordpress

preciso posicionar o campo de cep antes do endereço pois vou carregar o endereço utilizando a api dos correios, consigo posicionar os demais campos, porem o "billing_postcode" não obedece a ordem, o que pode ser?

```
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "order_fields", 30);
function order_fields($fields) {
    $fields["billing"]["billing_cpf_cli"]["priority"] = 8;
    $fields["billing"]["billing_rg_cli"]["priority"] = 9;
    $fields["billing"]["billing_postcode"]["priority"] = 10;
    $fields["billing"]["billing_address_1"]["priority"] = 11;
    $fields["billing"]["billing_num_cli"]["priority"] = 20;
    $fields["billing"]["billing_bairro_cli"]["priority"] = 21;  



    return $fields;
}       


add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields');
```

Answer (score -1):

Uma forma mais amigável de lidar com este tipo de problema relacionado a prioridade dos campos é avaliando através do inspecionador de elementos do seu navegador a prioridade em que os campos atuais estão, assim você consegue se orientar mais rapidamente. No inspecionador de elementos, procure por `data-priority="NÚMERO DA PRIORIDADE DO CAMPO"`

Em uma página checkout padrão do WooCommerce o *address_1* tem prioridade 50, logo basta colocar o *postcode* em 50 e o *address_1* em 55, por exemplo. Pelo que percebi no seu código, você está tentando alterar a prioridade através do *woocommerce_checkout_fields*, porém neste caso é o *woocommerce_default_address_fields* que você precisa modificar a prioridade, então uma solução para o seu problema seria:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'woocommerce_default_address_fields_reorder' );

function woocommerce_default_address_fields_reorder( $fields ) {
    $fields['postcode']['priority'] = 50; // antes era o address_1 que ocupava esta prioridade baseado no padrão WooCommerce de prioridades.
    $fields['address_1']['priority'] = 55;

    return $fields;
}
```

Recomendo que você dê uma lida na própria [documentação do WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) para entender melhor como é todo esse funcionamento.

Espero ter ajudado,

abraços!

Answer (score -1):

Sua função está errada, o correto é:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'woocommerce_checkout_fields_order' );
function woocommerce_checkout_fields_order( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_cpf_cli']['priority'] = 8;
    $fields['billing']['billing_rg_cli']['priority'] = 9;
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['priority'] = 10;
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['priority'] = 11;
    $fields['billing']['billing_num_cli']['priority'] = 12;
    $fields['billing']['billing_bairro_cli']['priority'] = 13;
    return $fields;
}
```

Woocommerce não reconhece essa funcção que chamou `function order_fields` o correto é `woocommerce_checkout_fields`.
Faça e veja se vai funcionar...
O ideal tambem seria reorganizar todos os campos porque assim voce iria definir desde preioridade 1 a infinito.